# How to properly remove Dead Banana tree leaves

Tags: fruit-trees, banana

Do I need to cut dead leaves by the trunk or I can just peel it all the way down?
Seems as when peeling to the ground there is a lot of water/moist there.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  As a general guideline, more information and pictures are a great way to get your specific questions answered.

Answer (score 2):

Without more input from you the best advice would be to cut the leaf off at the trunk.  Do not pull or strip.  Please send a photo or at least some sort of response...